# How and with what help to build a js package, which will include and use all used dependencies

Tags: javascript, npm

I have a `js` file that will use a third party library installed with `npm`. This file will be downloaded to the project when we go to a certain page.
Since the third-party library is used only on this page, I do not want to include it in the project, that is, I want to download it along with the js package. What I need to use for creating a js package which will contain all dependencies? I've been looking all day, but I can't find the solution.

Comment: Look into https://parceljs.org/

Comment: Your question confused me, are you using node.js ? beacuse in node.js your all the dependencies will go inside the package.json file.

Comment: @SumitYadav No, i'm using pure js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the situation like this: I copied the content of a third-party library and pasted it into a JS file before my code.

It can also be done using a webPacker by this [guide](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/webpack/merge-multiple-javascript-into-single-file-for-global-scope/)